# Mostrar un slider con imagenes del producto (woocommerce - wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, woocommerce

Tengo un tema de wordpress integrado con woocommerce.
Un producto puede ser subido con múltiples imágenes. Quiero que se muestre un slider con las imágenes de ese producto. ¿Hay algún plugin o una forma rápida de hacerlo?

Comment: Recomendado Fusion Slider. Es el mejor y mas fácil para manipular!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si, el WooSlider, te permite añadir sliders en los productos, que es lo que buscas y también en las entradas, te dejo el enlace, espero que te ayude 
 [WooSlider](https://woocommerce.com/products/wooslider/)

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación.